# Laravel 5.4 Auth::User() with relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

I have Table Vendors (for test Auth relationship) and Table Vendor_users,

But i use  `Auth::user()` it not relationship

[image]

And This Database

[image]

In Vendor model

```
    protected $table = 'vendor_users';
 public function Vendor_test(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor_test::class);
    }
```

And Vendor_test model

```
 protected $table = 'vendors';

public function Vendor(){
    return $this->hasMany(Vendor::class);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Relationship not working

Comment: Then why you mention Auth::user() in question?

Comment: i use dd(Auth::user()) for check to this user have vendor yet

Comment: So what is not working relationship or auth? Which model has information about the user?

Comment: relationship not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174693/discussion-between-dsraj-and-story-ks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the discussion and the table structure you have, 
Add the relation function in your model `vendor_users`.

```
protected $table = 'vendor_users';
public function vendor_contact() 
{ 
   return $this->belongsTo(Vendor_contact::class, 'vendor_contact_id'); 
}
```

get the user with the `vendor_contact` and check

```
$user = Auth::user()->with('vendor_contact')->first(); //  As you asked with for auth
//OR
$user = Auth::user()->load('vendor_contact'); // From the rkj answer as I found this good.
// OR
$user = Vendor::find(1)->with('vendor_contact')->first(); 
dd($user);
```

Answer (score 4):

from chat and your current table structure, you should have relation like this

in Vendor Model

```
public function vendor_contact() 
{ 
  return $this->belongsTo(Vendor_contact::class, 'vendor_contact_id'); 
}
```

in Vendor_contact Model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'vendContactId'; //check this 

public function vendor() 
{ 
  return $this->hasOne(Vendor::class, 'vendor_contact_id'); 
}
```

Now use lazy eager loading for loading `vendor_contact` relationship

```
Auth::user()->load('vendor_contact');
dd(Auth::user());
```

Comment: Yo rkj, on another post, your lazy loading solves the issue but I have a question. Why does on environment testing it doesn't load the relationship? It does on debug/production

Comment: but callng Auth::user()->relationshipname works on environment production. Any idea why it doesn't on environment testing?